# guacamole vnc viewer - how to?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, vnc, guacamole

I have my Tomcat server running, I downloaded the Guacamole VNC Viewer, and I followed the instructions on: http://guacamole.sourceforge.net/

However when I type :http://localhost:8080/guacamole/  I get error message:

> http status 404 The requested resource () is not available.

Anyone using Guacamole, can you explain the steps to follow? I moved the xml files and the war file as instructed, but there is this folder: "guacamole-src.tar" where do i unzip it to?
What are the steps to follow to make it work?

Comment: @chadix I did? Cant remember and [judging by your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240633/web-based-vnc-client), I'd say it was Dolph, not me. My suggestion would be to retag this "Java Tomcat Guacamole Vnc Debug" and once you got the thing running, ask another question about the XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've copied guacamole.war, start the server and check if a folder /guacamole is created at the same place (that means the server has found your web application and is trying to deploy it).

Also, please check your Tomcat logs.

You don't need to use guacamole-src.tar, that file only contains the project sources, but it is not needed.